# How to know pop event happened inside Nested Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I am currently building app where I need to use Nested Routing keeping one screen same and routing on different one. I want to when that second route is popped so that I can change value of expanded to fill whole screen. [Gist in Github](https://gist.github.com/ratnadeep007/00e0237f71a5f8a3d645129a97cebde0).
Here is code sample:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(body: MyHomePage()),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with RouteAware {
  bool rightPanelIsShown;
  Widget child;
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey();
  final RouteObserver<PageRoute> _routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      rightPanelIsShown = false;
      child = Container();
    });
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context));
    setState(() {
      child = Container();
    });
  }

  @override
  void didPop() {
    super.didPop();
    print('popped');
    setState(() {
      rightPanelIsShown = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("dis");
    _routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Center(
              child: FlatButton(
                color: Colors.blue,
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  rightPanelIsShown = !rightPanelIsShown;
                  child = Page1();
                }),
                child: Text(
                  'Open Right Panel',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          rightPanelIsShown
              ? Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Navigator(
                    onGenerateRoute: (route) => MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => child,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page1({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Page1',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30.0,
            ),
          ),
          _buildGoToButton(context),
          _buildBackbutton(context)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  FlatButton _buildGoToButton(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      color: Colors.green,
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => Page2(),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Text(
        'Go To Page 2',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21.0),
      ),
    );
  }

  FlatButton _buildBackbutton(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      color: Colors.red,
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: Text(
        'Close',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page2({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Page2',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30.0,
            ),
          ),
          _buildBackButton(context)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  FlatButton _buildBackButton(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      color: Colors.red,
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: Text(
        'Close',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Screencast of built upto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlWio.gif)

When click on close on right panel Page1 it should also change state of parent.
Thanks,

### Update

Working with help of João Soares

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(body: MyHomePage()),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with RouteAware {
  bool rightPanelIsShown;
  Widget child;
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey();
  final RouteObserver<PageRoute> _routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      rightPanelIsShown = false;
      child = Container();
    });
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context));
    setState(() {
      child = Container();
    });
  }

  @override
  void didPop() {
    super.didPop();
    print('popped');
    setState(() {
      rightPanelIsShown = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("dis");
    _routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    onPressed: () => setState(() {
                      rightPanelIsShown = !rightPanelIsShown;
                      child = Page1(
                        callback: onPop,
                      );
                    }),
                    child: Text(
                      'Open Right Panel 1',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    onPressed: () => setState(() {
                      rightPanelIsShown = !rightPanelIsShown;
                      child = Page3(
                        callback: onPop,
                      );
                    }),
                    child: Text(
                      'Open Right Panel 2',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          rightPanelIsShown
              ? Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: PanelView(
                    child: child,
                  ),
                )
              : Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  onPop(value) {
    print("popped");
    setState(() {
      rightPanelIsShown = false;
    });
  }
}

class PanelView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  PanelView({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PanelViewState createState() => _PanelViewState();
}

class _PanelViewState extends State<PanelView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      onGenerateRoute: (route) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          return Container(
            child: widget.child,
          );
        });
      },
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function callback;
  const Page1({Key key, this.callback}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Page1',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30.0,
            ),
          ),
          _buildGoToButton(context),
          _buildBackbutton(context)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  FlatButton _buildGoToButton(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      color: Colors.green,
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => Page2(),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Text(
        'Go To Page 2',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21.0),
      ),
    );
  }

  FlatButton _buildBackbutton(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      color: Colors.red,
      onPressed: () {
        callback('hello');
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
      child: Text(
        'Close',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page2({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Page2',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30.0,
            ),
          ),
          _buildBakButton(context)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  FlatButton _buildBakButton(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      color: Colors.red,
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: Text(
        'Close',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page3 extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function callback;
  const Page3({Key key, this.callback}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Page2',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30.0,
            ),
          ),
          _buildBakButton(context)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  FlatButton _buildBakButton(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      color: Colors.red,
      onPressed: () {
        callback('page3');
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: Text(
        'Close',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If there is better solution where I don't have to pass callback to every child widget of PanelView like if have 2 buttons in left panel and it determines which widget will be shown in right panel where button child determines child widget setting it in state.

Comment: return an int value (Ex. Page no.) on close event

Comment: Can you please clarify how/where to do that. On Page1 I can send value using Navigator.pop(context, 1) but where to use it and how?

Comment: Are these lines mandatory ??? rightPanelIsShown
              ? Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Navigator(
                    onGenerateRoute: (route) => MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => child,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : Container(),    **** because i suggest you to use buttons to navigation

Comment: Yes, cause this is only way I found to get desired output. You can check gif link in original question for output. As I need left side to be fixed and right side have it's own routing. There can be multiple buttons on left which can change right side widget and then there will be nested widget on right side.

Comment: I would suggest using a different solution than integrating a Navigator Widget directly on your main view if you then need to pass data from that navigator back to your main view. I will write some code that I think will do what you want, but it might take some tie.

Comment: Sure, that would be helpful. Thanks. @JoãoSoares

Answer (score -1):

If you are writing all your code in the same class, you can just call a function from your main class inside the Navigator:

**Widget**

```
Navigator(
  onGenerateRoute: (route) => MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) {
      return Container(
        color: Colors.orange,
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Close panel'),
          onPressed: () {
            panelClosed("I'm sending data back");
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          }
        )
      );
    }
  ),
),
```

**Method**

```
void panelClosed(data){
  print("Panel closed");
  setState(() {
    message = data;
  });
}
```

---

If instead you want your Navigator in a separate class, then you just need to pass down the function you want to call from the parent class to the child class like this:

**Widget in parent class**

```
Expanded(
  flex: 1,
  child: PanelView(callBack: panelClosed,)
)
```

**Method**

```
void panelClosed(data){
  print("Panel closed");
  setState(() {
    message = data;
  });
}
```

**The class with the navigator**

```
class PanelView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function callBack;

  PanelView({this.callBack});

  @override
  _PanelViewState createState() => _PanelViewState();
}

class _PanelViewState extends State<PanelView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      onGenerateRoute: (route) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('panel 2'),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Close'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      widget.callBack('send any data here');
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    }
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out in example project and also on main product and update here.

Comment: Cool. I'll await your feedback.

Comment: Thanks for solution, I updated the code in question and in [Gist](https://gist.github.com/ratnadeep007/00e0237f71a5f8a3d645129a97cebde0). If there is better solution for scenario like where child widget will change and I don't have to pass callback function to every new child widget of panel view is most welcome.