# Trigger animations on widget load flutter

Tags: flutter

So, I have a `AnimatedPositioned` widget in my widget tree, which contains a form. I want the `AnimatedPositioned` widget to slide up from bottom when user navigates to the screen. Now, there are many tutorials which show how to do this when user clicks a button using the `setState` method. But how do I trigger this automatically when this screen is loaded?

Comment: Maybe this link will give you an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59660086/how-to-know-pop-event-happened-inside-nested-widget-in-flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "right" way to do that would be **not** to use an implicit animation widget like `AnimatedPositioned` and instead use an explicit animation. Where you start your `AnimationController` in the `initState` of a `StatefulWidget`.

But just technically you could set the "destination" values for your `AnimatedPositioned` widget in a `Future` so that the value changes on the next frame. You try remoing the Future to see that otherwise the widget renders at its end position.

**This way is not recommended but possible:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double _dist = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(children: [
        AnimatedPositioned(
          child: Text('Hello Words'),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
          left: _dist,
          top: _dist,
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future(() {
      setState(() {
        _dist = 250.0;
      });
    });
  }
}
```